# xml SelectNodes method using a PowerShell script returns no nodes (namespace issues?)

Tags: powershell, xml

I'm trying to edit an xml document using a PowerShell script.

This is the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>libs-release</id>
            <username>USERNAME</username>
            <password>PASSWORD</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>plugins-release</id>
            <username>USERNAME</username>
            <password>PASSWORD</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>0eb153056152</id>
            <username>USERNAME</username>
            <password>PASSWORD</password>
        </server>
        
    </servers>
    
</settings>
```

This is the PowerShell script.

```
$file = "C:\Users\XXXXXXXXX\Downloads\config\maven_settings.xml"

[xml]$xml = Get-Content $file

$xml.SelectNodes("//username")
```

The scrip returns no nodes. But, when I remove the attributes of `<settings>` tag, it works and returns the required nodes. Is this is an issue with the namespaces? How do I resolve it while keeping the namespace attributes in the original xml document?

Comment: try using `select-xml` instead of XMLNode.SelectNodes. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-7.2
This returns node output for me. it needs parsed and formatted, but it works: `select-xml -xml $xml -XPath "//username"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```ps
$xml.settings.servers.server.username
```

However, as advised by @Frank Thomas in the comments, Select-Xml cmdlet is better compared to the above approach (you need to need the hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

What Frank and the member dot referencing that 'Reddy' showed (which I had in this response as well, but pulled it out once his post landed) are a prudent route, Yet, if you are hankering for use SelectNodes, then:

```
$MyXml.SelectNodes('/*/*/*')
# Results
<#
id              username password
--              -------- --------
libs-release    USERNAME PASSWORD
plugins-release USERNAME PASSWORD
0eb153056152    USERNAME PASSWORD
#>

($MyXml.SelectNodes('/*/*/*')).username
# Results
<#
username
--------
USERNAME
USERNAME
USERNAME
#>
```

All things considered. It's just like the member reference approach, just without having to type all member names explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You need set namespace before select nodes\values etc.

Try next

```
$Namespace = @{
        nsa = ($xmlDoc.GetEnumerator() | ? { -not  [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.NamespaceURI) } ).NamespaceURI
    }
```

then

```
Select-Xml -XPath $xpath -Xml $xmlDoc -Namespace $Namespace
```

"nsa" - any word for you taste.
with SelectNodes I сould not use namespace, although this overload indicated in the MS document